# Divide by maximum within a group in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, max

I do have a dataframe below:

```
cola colb 
 a    10  
 a    12
 a    30  
 b    20  
 b    25
```

I would like to add new column like: for each group find the maximum and then calculate

newcol=(max(withingroupcola)-colb)/max(withingroupcola) within each group like below:

```
cola colb    newcol
 a    10   (30-10)/30 
 a    12   (30-12)/30  
 a    30   (30-30)/30
 b    20   (25-20)/25
 b    25   (25-25)/25
```

and then sort within group desc. How can I do that in pandas dataframe? Please help.
Thank you.

Not:I am trying to scale if there is a function for scaling please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new `Series`, then first subtract by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and then divide by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
s = df.groupby('cola')['colb'].transform('max')
df['new'] = s.sub(df['colb']).div(s)

print (df)
  cola  colb       new
0    a    10  0.666667
1    a    12  0.600000
2    a    30  0.000000
3    b    20  0.200000
4    b    25  0.000000
```

Another solution, slowier:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('cola')['colb'].apply(lambda x: (x.max()- x) / x.max())
```

Comment: Thank you but I also need to sort. How can I do that?